# NLP : What are some common verbs surrounding organization names in text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to come up with some rules to detect named entities, specifically company or organization names in text. I think it makes sense to focus on verbs. There are a lot of `POS Taggers` that can easily detect proper nouns. I personally like `StanfordPOSTagger`. Now, once i have the proper noun, i know that it is a named entity. However, to be certain that it is the name of a company, i need to come up with rules and possibly `Gazetteers`

I was thinking of focusing on verbs. Is there a set of common verbs that occur frequently around company names?

I could create an annotated corpus and explicitly train a Machine Learning classifier to predict such verbs, but that is a LOT of work. It would be great if someone has already done some research on this.

Additionally, can some other `POS` tags give clues? Not just verbs.

Comment: why the downvote? should i post this in datascience group?

Answer (score 3):

The verbs approach seems the most promising. I've been working on something myself to identify sentient beings from folktales. See more about my approach here: http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/INT/INT7/paper/viewFile/9253/9204
You may still need to do some annotations and training OR use web text and the method below to find the training data.

If you are looking for real companies (i.e. non-fictional),  then I'd suggest you just extract referring expressions (i.e. nouns and also multi-word expressions) and then check against an online database (some with easy to use API) like:

- https://angel.co/api (startups)
- https://data.crunchbase.com/
- http://www.metabase.com/
- http://www.opencalais.com/ (paid options)
- http://wiki.dbpedia.org/ (wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

Does the [Stanford NER system](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) fit this use-case? It already detects organizations, alongside people and other named entity types.

Comment: yes it does! and thats what i was working with. The problem is, sometimes it does not tag organizations properly

Comment: thats why i wanted to augment the tagging

Comment: You can take a look at [TokensRegexNER](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java) as a potential way to augment Stanford NER with custom gazetteers. But, I suspect you'll have a hard time getting significant improvements from second-guessing the trained NER system, with anything other than a gazetteer. The common cases you allude to in the question are likely already captured in the NER model.

Comment: Wink ;P , you can use commercial systems and you can see the difference in "quality" (though usually not empirically tested like in academic papers).